# Combine DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have to connect and read data from 10 databases and save data as pandas data frame. After combining dataframes, I have an empty dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns={'name', 'ip'})

# in a loop I connect to db and read sql data and combine data 

for db in database_list:
  db_df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, con)
  df1 = df1.append(db_df)
  df1 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset='name', keep='last')

print df1
```

df1 is an empty dataframe. What is the correct way for combine dataframes in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can append each `DataFrame` to `list` and last [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) all to one big `df`:

```
dfs = []
for db in database_list:
  db_df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, con)
  print db_df
  db_df = db_df.drop_duplicates(subset='name', keep='last')
  dfs.append(db_df)

df1 = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
print df1
```

Comment: with list I have `
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
` error

Comment: Hmmmm, `db_df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, con)` return for you `DataFrame`? Can you check it?

Comment: yes it is a dataframe, I think I do the wrong thing in drop duplicates